# Перевод буквы в нижний регистр

Tags: delphi-xe

Есть строки вот такого плана:

```
Price=123:Acf3456
Ac_number=123(A):Gpm456

Price=5678:Bms3456
Ac_number=5678(B):Kprt456
```

Как перевести **первую букву после двоеточия** в нижний регистр. На выходе результат:

```
Price=123:acf3456
Ac_number=123(A):gpm456

Price=5678:bms3456
Ac_number=5678(B):kprt456
```

То есть буквы что в тексте возле двоеточия **:A :G :B :K** - должны стать маленькими **:a :g :b :k**. Знаю есть функция но она переводит всю строку.

```
   s  := AnsiLowerCase(s);
```

Вот так еще можно перевести первую букву, но вот как после двоеточия:

```
if s<>'' then
  s[1] := AnsiUpperCase(s[1])[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Все решила свой вопрос! Сама додумалась :). И ответ:

```
i:= Pos(':', s) + 1;
if s<>'' then
s[i] := AnsiLowerCase(s[i])[1];
```